# What is the track in bloom-release needed for?

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not get why this is needed for. Some of the documentation and some of the answers on this topic are deprecated.

Because e.g. the link in http://answers.ros.org/question/59505/where-to-find-existing-track-in-release-repository/ is broken I'd also like to know the current state on that answer so:

Is the track like a branch for the specific ROS version or could I use the same track e.g. for indigo and jade? Where is this information used / stored? Do I always have to specify a track?

> In the bloom-release command you ran
> above, you specified the --track. By
> convention you should create tracks
> with the same name as the ROS distro
> you are releasing for, but you could
> name your track what ever you wanted.

This means to me that it does not matter any longer..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252077/what-is-the-track-in-bloom-release-needed-for?/) by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:\

> This means to me that it does not matter any longer..

From a language perspective: the name *itself* doesn't matter, that sentence does not tell you that you can re-use tracks for different ROS distributions.

You could use `joe` as a track name for Indigo, and `jack` for Kinetic fi.

**Comment by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on 2017-01-16**:
So I can only use it to provide an alias for the rosdistro names? And what purpose does this have?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
I was only commenting on your implied "the text seems to tell me it doesn't matter what I do" remark. I did not say anything about the technical implications / implementation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
I've updated the link in #q59505. Not sure how that influences your understanding of things though.

**Comment by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) on 2017-01-16**:
Okay thanks. Not really though :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The idea behind a track was that you could make multiple releases for the same ROS distro. Bloom, doesn't actually care about the ROS distro in all cases. You could have have a track called `debian_sid` or `version_x.y, for example which isn't tied to a ROS distribution. We don't end up doing that very often, so the recommendation is to just match the track name to the ROS distribution. See:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/181

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3